# Cannot read property 'Reactstrap' of undefined When adding @babel/transform-runtime plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, reactstrap

I'm working on the frontend website using react js, and the webpack loader. while in development mode I did not encounter any problems, but when I built the project and got the static file I got an error: Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'Reactstrap' of undefined.
But the error will disappear during development mode if I delete the plugin: `@babel/transform-runtime`, but in production mode an error will appear
Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined.

```
module.exports = {
             entry: path.join(__dirname, "/src/index.js"),
            module: 
                {
                    rules:[ 
                        {
                            test: /\.js$/,
                            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            query: {
                                presets: [ "@babel/react","@babel/env" ],
                                plugins: [
                                    '@babel/transform-runtime', 
                                ]
                            }
                        },
```

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Error Solved, helper cause conflict in function
so I'm added this in .babelrc

```
[
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        {
          "absoluteRuntime": false,
          "corejs": false,
          "helpers": false,
          "regenerator": true,
          "useESModules": true,
          "version": "7.0.0-beta.0"
        }
      ]
```